# python PDFKIT wkhtml2pdf: trying to print google translate web pages translations via powershell script

Tags: powershell, scripting, wkhtmltopdf

My idea looks simple:

1. A file with the $(google translate prefix)+$url per line
2. A Power Shell script thats launchs this code for each line:

```
     ForEach ($url in Get-Content $textfile) {
      wkhtmltopdf.exe -l --no-stop-slow-scripts --minimum-font-size 12 --load-error-handling ignore --javascript-delay 25000 "$url" "$path$i$ext"
      $script:i++
 }
```

I get this kind of result:
[pdf generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv7ZV.png)

So also this errors on console:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Warning: SSL error ignored
Warning: SSL error ignored
Warning: SSL error ignored
Warning: SSL error ignored
Warning: SSL error ignored
Warning: SSL error ignored
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)                     ] 50%
Warning: Failed to load https://panel.ondestek.com/client/client.js?s=d35164ea-2122-4654-967e-ddf61b4ee4b2 (ignore)
Counting pages (2/6)
Warning: Received createRequest signal on a disposed ResourceObject's NetworkAccessManager. This might be an indication of an iframe taking too long to load.
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
Error: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol "about" is unknown
Warning: Received createRequest signal on a disposed ResourceObject's NetworkAccessManager. This might be an indication of an iframe taking too long to load.
Warning: Received createRequest signal on a disposed ResourceObject's NetworkAccessManager. This might be an indication of an iframe taking too long to load.
```

So if someone has found this case before, I'll be grateful.

Thank you very much.